# SQL- listing people who did not contribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an SQL task where it asks to "Show a list of persons with First Name and Last Name, who did not contribute in any composition."

Here is what I've attempted, but to no avail.

```
select * from (select count(a.person_id)num,a.first_name ||' '|| a.last_name name
  from LABPRJ_PERSON a, LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL w
  where a.person_id=w.person_id group by last_name, a.first_name
  union
  select 0,a.first_name ||' '|| a.last_name name from LABPRJ_PERSON a where person_id not in (select person_id
  from LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL)) where num = 0;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need this, as far as I can tell:

```
SELECT * FROM LABPRJ_PERSON WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NOT EXISTS`, it has better performance than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name FROM LABPRJ_PERSON p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL c ON c.person_id = p.person_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU ARE USING SQL SERVER PLEASE TRY THIS ONE.

```
SELECT
  CAST(A.FIRST_NAME AS  AS VARCHAR(MAX))  + ' '+  CAST(A.LAST_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  FROM 
      LABPRJ_PERSON A
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 
        B.PERSON_ID 
    FROM
        LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL B WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last_name, first_name 
FROM LABPRJ_PERSON AS T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
LABPRJ_COMPOSITION_DETAIL AS T2
ON T1.person_id=T2.person_id
WHERE T2.person_id IS NULL;
```